When implementing Firebase Storage and Firebase Messaging in Android Studio at the same time there is duplicate errors occurring?


This is all the libraries I implement in build.gradle

When messaging stands alone it does't give any error

But when implement 2 library storage and messaging at the same time it has the following error
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.Timestamp found in modules firebase-common-21.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:21.0.0) and firebase-firestore-24.10.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.10.3)

This is the usage of messaging
-

This is the usage of storage




Please edit your question and add the content of your libs.versions.toml file.

To resolve you can use one of the below when using both:
implementation (libs.firebase.storage){
exclude("com.google.firebase.Timestamp")
}

or

implementation (libs.firebase.messaging){
exclude("com.google.firebase.Timestamp")
}

The reason is that this package is included in both dependencies and you have to exclude one of them to make them worked perfectly.
